# Hard Drive Beeping during installation of Mavricks

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive

My OSX is running just fine, thought I upgrade to Mavricks.  Ran the installer, and it eventually rebooted. Another Mavricks installer screen popped up and told me wait 45 min.  5 minutes into it, my external hard drive (my only drive in this system) started beeping.  Eventually it said the installation has problems, click here to go back to your old OS. It restarted back to my old OS without any problems.  What do I do now.  Get a new Hard drive? Run some software to exclude whatever sectors it had trouble writing to?

Comment: A hdd beeping is a bad sign.  They should not do that.  Have you looked up what that means exactly?

Comment: I'm confused, your EXTERNAL hard drive (USB?) started beeping? Were you trying to install mavericks on your ext drive? Which version of OSX are you upgrading from?